# After update 15.04 to 15.40 VLC app did not work

Tags: updates

I've tried to upgrate VLC, with sudo commands it was not possible.
Now I get some errors when trying to upgrade the system like:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: It looks like the PPA doesn't have any packages for ...15.40, or whatever you've upgraded to.

Answer (score 0):

The ppa you used to install VLC does not have binaries for Ubuntu 15.10.

You can disable this PPA and install VLC from official repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```